# Как нарисовать сплошной круг в matplotlib по формуле?

Tags: python, математика, matplotlib, sympy

Формула такая:

```
{x = R * cos(t), y = R * sin(t)},
```

где R - функция (отрезок) от a до b (Например от 0 до 4)

```
plot_parametric(R*cos(t),R*sin(t),(R,0,4))
```

не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# встроенная функция
# закрашенная окружность fill=True, незакрашенная fill=False
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r', fill=True)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(circle1)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Параметрическая кривая

```
ax = plt.gca()

# Массивы x, y

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
r = 1
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)

ax.plot(x, y)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```